# Marker locked at the top in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have an issue that keeps reappearing whenever I use Vim. Sometimes, I'm not sure how I manage, the window moves with the cursor so that the line I'm on is always the top one. I've been looking around but been unable to find how to revert this.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you check if you had a mapping like `j -> jzt`? that would make your cursor line always on top. do a `:verbose  map j`

Comment: Thanks for replying. It didn't find anything unfortunately...  All I have added in my _vimrc is :colorscheme desert, :map <F12> :tabn <ENTER> and :set number.

Comment: @Kent So the issue had to do with Vim on Windows being weird with the Win + arrow keys. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured out what is causing this so I'll answer myself if anyone stumbles upon this problem in the future: It has to do with Vim on Windows (in my case 10) acting up when resizing the window using the Win + arrow keys. So just dont do that and you'll be fine